# FTP & WGET remote file upload fail

Tags: linux, kali-linux, wget, ftp, upload

I'm using virtualbox with kali linux installed.
While on SSH shell, i used wget to upload resources from my host machine but it's failing, FTP put  command fails too.

The following are the command line snippet for FTP

```
ftp> put rev2.exe
local: rev2.exe remote: rev2.exe
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||49196|)
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
100% |**********************************************************************************************************************************************************************| 74172       72.28 KiB/s    --:-- ETA

421 Service not available, remote server timed out. Connection closed.
74172 bytes sent in 01:01 (1.18 KiB/s)
ftp> bye
```

The connection gets timed out before the file is fully uploaded

The following are the command line snippet for WGET

```
www-data@dmv:/var/www/html$ wget http://10.18.75.19/pspy64
wget http://10.18.75.19/pspy64
--2023-08-07 11:52:48--  http://10.18.75.19/pspy64
Connecting to 10.18.75.19:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3104768 (3.0M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: 'pspy64'
```

Shell is stuck at "Saving to: 'pspy64'"

I tried changing VM from Bridged to NAT and disabled passive mode on FTP.
Firewall is disabled

note: low-size files can be uploaded on both FTP and WGET.

Comment: FTP is a really archaic protocol for transferring files. Why not just use SFTP (AKA SCP). On windows you can use [winscp](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php). It uses your regular SSH connection details

Comment: Is this a binary or a script? Your ftp is in ASCII mode, not binary.

Comment: there's no SSH involved in what you describe as SSH?

Comment: virtualbox has own way for exposing a directory from host to guest, have you tried it? Also, are you sure you have enough free space and file system is not somehow broken?

Comment: https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

Comment: thank you guys for your inputs, i'm doing HackTheBox and i use old technologies like FTP only for the sake of solving the challenge 
also i was talking about wget and not SSH, my bad